# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I'm trying to understand regex and i have an error message.
I don't understand this message because I don't use list. If I use just print(number) it doesn't delete the [ ] of the result. The goal is to obtain only the number in the sentence as result.
I use python 3.6.

Below my code:

```
import re
user_sentence = input(">>> : ")
while user_sentence != "quit":
  if re.findall("[0-9]+", user_sentence):
    number = re.findall("[0-9]+", user_sentence)
    print(number.group())
    user_sentence = input(">>> : ")
 else:
    print("no")
    user_sentence = input(">>> : ")
```

Answer (score 0):

`groups()` (with an `s`) is on the return value of a `re.match`, not a `findall`. If you're looking to print each item in the list returned by a findall, you can print use `join` to join them on a space, or loop over the list. Note that the list may include tuples though (not in your case, but in general). Example of joining them on a space:

```py
import re

user_sentence = input(">>> : ")

while user_sentence != "quit":
    if re.findall("[0-9]+", user_sentence):
        number = re.findall("[0-9]+", user_sentence)
        print(" ".join(number))
        user_sentence = input(">>> : ")
    else:
        print("no")
        user_sentence = input(">>> : ")
```

Or by looping over and printing:

```py
        for n in number:
            print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you running `re.findall` twice ? Your code should be like this:

```py
import re
user_sentence = input(">>> : ")
while user_sentence != "quit":
  numbers = re.findall("[0-9]+", user_sentence)
  if numbers:
    print("found numbers " + " ".join(numbers))
    user_sentence = input(">>> : ")
 else:
    print("no numbers found")
    user_sentence = input(">>> : ")
```

Answer (score -1):

findall returns list type by default and list does not have any such method/attribute. If you try to running print (number), you see a list as the output. But to convert the list elements into number you can add these lines after you have evaluated number

```
number = re.findall("[0-9]+", user_sentence)
#add these lines
for num in number :
      result = result + str(num)
 print (int(result))
```